# Codeigniter - loading of model creates an issue with instances

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, instance

I'm using CodeIgniter and have created several classes (in my model folder):

- `Entity` is an abstract class (used to represent anything that will be in a form and go into a database)
- `Login` extends `Entity` (used to manage user logins: username, password...)
- `Webform` (used to create a form based the Entity)

In my controller I have this:

```
$this->load->model('login');
$myLogin = new Login(array('stuff' => 'value'));
$form = new Webform($myLogin);
```

In my models I have the Webform class:

```
class Webform
{
    protected $entity;
    protected $fields;

    public function __construct(Entity $entity)
    {
        $this->setEntity($entity);
    }

    public function setEntity(Entity $entity)
    {
        $this->entity = $entity;
    }
}
```

I get errors when the "Webform" model is loaded in `config/autoload.php` (at least I think it is there, because the controller code works just fine and the view displays below these 3 errors):

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 4096
Message: Argument 1 passed to Webform::__construct() must be an instance of Entity, none given, called in (...)\system\core\Loader.php on line 303 and defined
Filename: forms/webform.php
Line Number: 8

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: entity
Filename: forms/webform.php
Line Number: 10

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 4096
Message: Argument 1 passed to Webform::setEntity() must be an instance of Entity, null given, called in (...)\application\models\forms\webform.php on line 10 and defined
Filename: forms/webform.php
```

As far as I can see the CI autoload insists that there should be an `Entity` - but all I want here is for CI to know where to look when I will do a `$foo = new Webform($bar);`

What I am doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT - FIXED (I think)
I think I got it - CI loading the class was like instantiating it - instead of loading it I did a good old require_once. It looks like it is working now.

Comment: you're passing an instance of `Login` to a parameter type of `Entity`

Comment: But Login inherits Entity (the abstract class) so that should be fine, no?

Comment: No. It still expects a value with type `Entity`

Comment: Entity being an abstract class it wouldn't work. My issue is that outside of Codeigniter this code works perfectly: any object which an instance of Login is also an instance of Entity and Webform is correctly constructed. I'm trying to integrate this code into CI and that's where there are weird error messages.

Comment: Actually after looking further into it, the issue is that when CI loads the model it cannot find $entity (Undefined variable: entity) to pass to: public function __construct(Entity $entity). I removed the "Entity" requirement and the issue remains that $entity doesn't exist and the way CI handles this creates errors.